# How to handle error when using multiple async request with Combine Framework

Tags: ios, swift, combine

I have a requirement to send two independent requests to two remote APIs and need to process both responses at once when both requests are completed. I did the basic implementation using Zip operator. It works really fine in the happy scenario. Please check below sample code.

```
import Foundation
import Combine

enum NetowrkError: Error {
    case decodingError
    case requestFailed
}

struct StudentDTO: Codable {
    let name: String
    let age: Int
    let addressId: Int
}

struct AddressDTO: Codable {
    let id: Int
    let town: String
}

struct Student {
    let name: String
    let age: Int
    let town: String
}

func m1<T: Codable>(url: String, type: T.Type) -> Future<T, NetowrkError> {
    return Future { promise in
//Send request using URLSessionDatatask
    }
}

Publishers.Zip(
    m1(url: "",type: [StudentDTO].self),
    m1(url: "",type: [AddressDTO].self)
).sink(receiveCompletion: { print($0) },
       receiveValue: { studentList, addresses in
    //Process Both Resutls and join Student and Address to have a single Model
    let addressDict = addresses.reduce(into: [Int: String]()) {
        print($1)
        $0[$1.id] = $1.town
    }
    let students = studentList.map { student in
        return Student(name: student.name, age: student.age, town: addressDict[student.addressId] ?? "")
    }
    //self?.processStudents(students: students)
})
```

But when it comes to error handling with the Zip operator it seems a bit difficult. Because the Zip operator emits only when both requests get successful. My requirement is to show an error message when a request to Studen API get failed but should be able to proceed in the app even if the call to address the endpoint get failed. How can I do it with Combine?

Comment: Hy, Use DispatchGroup to perform multiple async api request

Comment: Yeah.. That's a good suggestion. But I just tried to do it using Combine itself as I am already using it.

Answer (score 1):

In your case `replaceError(with:)` should help. With this function you can replace errors with a default value.

It would look somethink like this:

```
Publishers.Zip(
    m1(url: "",type: [StudentDTO].self),
    m1(url: "",type: [AddressDTO].self).replaceError(with: []).setFailureType(to: Error.self)
)
```

Answer (score -1):

When a Swift Combine publisher fails it completes. You can use the `.sink { completion in` operator to handle your error. This will even work if only one publisher emits an error.

e.g.:

```
.sink { completion in
    switch completion{
    case .finished:
        break
    case .failure(let error):
        //handle error here
    }
}
```

### Edit:

A more complete implementation would look like this:

```
Publishers.Zip(
    m1(url: "",type: [StudentDTO].self),
    m1(url: "",type: [AddressDTO].self)
)
.sink(receiveCompletion: { completion in
        switch completion{
        case .finished:
            break
        case .failure(let error):
            // handle error here
        }
    } , receiveValue: { studentList, addresses in
    //Process Both Resutls and join Student and Address to have a single Model
    let addressDict = addresses.reduce(into: [Int: String]()) {
        print($1)
        $0[$1.id] = $1.town
    }
    let students = studentList.map { student in
        return Student(name: student.name, age: student.age, town: addressDict[student.addressId] ?? "")
    }
    //self?.processStudents(students: students)
})
```

### Edit 2:

If you want to handle your errors separately you would need to do that inside your `.Zip` operator. `.mapError(...` seems appropriate for that.

e.g.:

```
Publishers.Zip(
    m1(url: "",type: [StudentDTO].self),
    m1(url: "",type: [AddressDTO].self)
        .mapError({ error in
            // handle error here and than return it so the publisher can finish
            return error
        })
)
```

Comment: Hi burnsi. I just want to get notified only when both requests are completed. Yes, we can handle errors by processing requests as separate publishers but, then I have to check whether the other request has been completed or not within the ".sink" completion handler. I'm trying to avoid that.

Comment: @nath I was under the impression this is about error handling. You can still use the `receiveValue` to handle the default success part. The `case .failure...` will only be called if one of the publishers emitts an error. And then it shouldn´t matter whether one failed or both.

Comment: @nath After reading your comment again. I didn´t argue to use 2 different publishers. I hope my expanded example makes it more clear.

Comment: yeah now I can get the error. Is there any way to know which API call failed?

Comment: @nath Well you could extend your error type to hold information about what call did fail. But the framework itself does not.

Comment: This is great. Let me try it and get back to you